# How to escape double quotes in bash command

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following command, which I am trying to append to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
echo 'alias N="cd $(pwd) && source ./bin/activate && cd new""
```

I want it to return echo:

```
alias N="cd /Users/david/Desktop/django2 && source ./bin/activate && cd new"
```

What would be the correct way to escape the `pwd` or quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo "alias N='cd $(pwd) && source ./bin/activate && cd new'"
```

However recommend you to use function instead of `alias`.

```
echo "N() { cd '$PWD' && source ./bin/activate && cd new; }"
```

Note use of `$PWD` instead of command `pwd`

Answer (score 2):

To echo a literal `"` inside of a double-quoted string, use the escape character `\`:

```
echo "alias N=\"cd $(pwd) && source ./bin/activate && cd new\""
```

Outputs on my box:

```
alias N="cd /home/bishop/ && source ./bin/activate && cd new"
```

However, your use case suggests to me a function:

```
go() {
    local where
    where=${1:-${PWD}}
    cd "${where}" && source ./bin/activate && cd new
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid excessive escaping with a here document:

```
cat >> ~/.bash_profile << EOF
alias N="cd $(pwd) && source ./bin/activate && cd new"
EOF
```